# What is the rationale behind Apache Jena's *everything is an interface if possible* design philosophy?

Tags: java, design-patterns, jena

If you are familiar with the [Java RDF and OWL engine Jena](http://jena.apache.org/), then you have run across their philosophy that everything should be specified as an interface when possible.  This means that a *Resource*, *Statement*, *RDFNode*, *Property*, and even the RDF *Model*, etc., are, contrary to what you might first think, *Interfaces* instead of concrete classes.

This leads to the use of Factories quite often.  Since you can't instantiate a *Property* or *Model*, you must have something else do it for you -- [the Factory design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

My question, then, is, what is the reasoning behind using this pattern as opposed to a traditional class hierarchy system *given the nature of the content the library aims to serve*? It is often perfectly viable to use either one.  For example, if I want a memory backed *Model* instead of a database-backed *Model* I could just instantiate those classes, I don't need to ask a Factory to give me one.

---

As an aside, I'm in the process of writing a library for manipulating [Pearltrees](http://www.pearltrees.com) data, which is exported from their website in the form of an RDF/XML document.  As I write this library, I have many options for defining the relationships present in the Peartrees data.  What is nice about the Pearltrees data is that it has a very logical class system: A tree is made up of pearls, which can be either Page, Reference, Alias, or Root pearls.

My question comes from trying to figure out if I should adopt the Jena philosophy in my library which uses Jena, or if I should disregard it, pick my own design philosophy, and stick with it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to differentiate this from other "why should I code to interfaces"-type questions.

Comment: @DaveNewton Perhaps it is more focused and pertains to a concrete example..

Comment: Either ask the Jena dev list or programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @bmargulies But I'm asking specifically about *Jena*.  Programmers is for general and more theoretical questions.  I know some of the Jena curators watch the SO Jena tag -- so I asked here as well.

Comment: This would make for an interesting question on Programmers.SE as it's a philosophical question, albeit inspired by a concrete example.

Comment: @DavidHarkness It's not quite philosophical.  I want to know why the people who wrote Jena decided to do it that way, not in general what's the benefit of an all interface design.  I don't see how this is different from the myriad of other "why was something implemented this way" questions which are popular and remain open on SO..

Comment: @DavidCowden - If you want an answer from the Jena team, the question is too specific for SO. If you want a more general answer such as "following this pattern is good/bad because . . ." the question is too general for SO. That's my assessment after rereading the FAQ.

Comment: *"I want to know why the people who wrote Jena decided to do it that way ..."* - What makes you think **they** want to discuss it?  Just make up your mind about what **you** want to do in **your** code.  (You could also look at some of the other "takes" on Java APIs for RDF etcetera to see if you find the alternative approaches more agreeable.)

Comment: @StephenC I don't disagree.  I'm just curious (=